# Flatten DataFrame into a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to reorganize the following mutli-row DataFrame,

```
       1          2       3
A  Apple     Orange   Grape
B    Car      Truck   Plane
C  House  Apartment  Garage
```

into this, single-row DataFrame.

```
     1_A     2_A    3_A  1_B    2_B    3_B    1_C        2_C     3_C
0  Apple  Orange  Grape  Car  Truck  Plane  House  Apartment  Garage
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`unstack` + `sort_index` to the rescue:

```
v = df.unstack().to_frame().sort_index(level=1).T
v.columns = v.columns.map('_'.join)
```

```
v
     1_A     2_A    3_A  1_B    2_B    3_B    1_C        2_C     3_C
0  Apple  Orange  Grape  Car  Truck  Plane  House  Apartment  Garage
```