# TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found when flattening MultiIndex pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have previously asked a similar question - [pandas - Reorganize a multi-row & multi-column DataFrame into single-row & multi-column DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556537/pandas-reorganize-a-multi-row-multi-column-dataframe-into-single-row-multi/50556569#50556569), however, when I use the provided solution:

```
v = df.unstack().to_frame().sort_index(level=1).T
v.columns = v.columns.map('_'.join)
```

on this following DataFrame (with switched column & row values compared to the example in the mentioned answer),

```
index      A          B       C
    1  Apple     Orange   Grape
    2    Car      Truck   Plane
    3  House  Apartment  Garage
```

However, this line: `v.columns = v.columns.map('_'.join)` throws the following Error: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found`

Is there any way to get the following output?

```
     A_1     A_2    A_3  B_1    B_2    B_3    C_1        C_2     C_3
0  Apple  Orange  Grape  Car  Truck  Plane  House  Apartment  Garage
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happens when your headers are integeral. Try using `.format` instead:

```
v = df.unstack().to_frame().T
v.columns = v.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

```
print(v)
     A_1  A_2    A_3     B_1    B_2        B_3    C_1    C_2     C_3
0  Apple  Car  House  Orange  Truck  Apartment  Grape  Plane  Garage
```