# How to write multiple arrays into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a code to write multiple arrays into one single data frame in panda where I append the data frame row by row . For example I have a row of [1,2,3,4,5] and next row of [6,7,8,9,10].
I want to print it as :
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
in a csv file. I want to write multiple rows like this in single csv file but all codes can be found only for appending a data frame column by column. Can I write this array row by row too?
Please help.

I tried using  pandas library but couldn't fine relevant command.

Comment: Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556537/flatten-dataframe-into-a-single-row

Comment: For clarification: in the end do you want just one line in the csv file? To me it is what it currently sounds like and the above link points to.

Answer (score 0):

the next code snippet might help you:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```